# Не получается прочитать файл изображения javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file

Tags: java, bufferedimage, javax

Проект Spring Boot, сборка мавен.
По пути есть файл

```
C:\Users\username\IdeaProjects\mail\src\main\resources\my_image.jpg
```

при его чтении `final BufferedImage imageFile = ImageIO.read(new File("my_image.jpg"));`

падает ошибка javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file

Почему так получается?

Comment: из ресурсов вы так не прочитаете. в данном случае ваш файл должен находится в корневом каталоге проекта, а не в папке ремурсов

Comment: спасибо ) да а есть вариант из ресурсов мавена это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы прочитать файл из папки ресурсов есть несколько путей. 
Например, так :

```
public Object loadFile(String filePath) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    try (final ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(PropertiesLoader.class
            .getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filePath)))) {
        return is.readObject();
    }
}
```

Если у вас спринг, можете использовать класс PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver. примерно так: new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver(this.getClass().getClassLoader())
                .getResources(...))